# I am not sure whether my window 7 exists after ubuntu installation

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

After i installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, I can not see the grub. I installed boot-repair but still no success. The following link has the description. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15088834/
Please let me know if I can get my Windows 7 back?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by this, you completely removed Windows 7 and replaced the entire system with Ubuntu.

```
Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1    *          2,048   483,512,319   483,510,272  83 Linux
/dev/sda2         483,514,366   500,117,503    16,603,138   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         483,514,368   500,117,503    16,603,136  82 Linux swap / Solaris

✂️----== snip ==----

=================== blkid:
/dev/sda1: UUID="e32ba978-5c81-4a46-90bb-8a0d3da07fb2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3e4743ee-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="53dfa072-a4d1-4147-959b-7704c899a0fe" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="3e4743ee-05"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="UUI" UUID="3278BBD178BB91D9" TYPE="ntfs"


1 disks with OS, 1 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 0 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.
```

If you actually had a Windows installation on this drive, you would have a partition on `/dev/sda` listed as NTFS.

There is no (feasable or guaranteed) way to get Windows back -- it's gone. If you really need Windows, I suggest getting out your backup.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm working on to recover the partitions with testdisk utility. Hope it works!

Comment: @M.EjazAhmed I wish you luck. It'd be interesting to hear of an OS recovery success story.